# Failed validating 'type' json schema

Tags: python, json

I've writen a small chunk os json schema but I'm getting a validation error using python jsonschema.

Here is my schema:

```
{


"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "output": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Type": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Value": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Default": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Description": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Options": {
              "type": "array"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "Type",
            "Value",
            "Default",
            "Description",
            "Options"
          ]
        },
        "Inverted": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Value": {
              "type": "bool"
            },
            "Default": {
              "type": "bool"
            },
            "Description": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "Type",
            "Value",
            "Default",
            "Description"
          ]
        },
        "Pulse Width": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Value": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "Default": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "Description": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "Type",
            "Value",
            "Default",
            "Description"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Type",
        "Inverted",
        "Pulse Width"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
Failed validating u'type' in schema
```

I'm attempting to validate my schema with:

```
schema = ""
with open(jsonSchemaFilePath, 'r') as schema_file:
    schema = schema_file.read()

try:
    Draft4Validator.check_schema(schema)
except SchemaError as schemaError:
    print schemaError
```

What am I doing wrong with the schema I've written? Am I not allowed to have a property named Type?

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect. I tried loading your JSON in my shell and it worked fine. Is `check_schema` expecting a json object?

Comment: `check_schema` was looking for a `dic`

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. You should mark your answer as correct!

Comment: Just did :-) Had to wait a couple days... Thanks for the reminder though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was `Draft4Validator.check_schema` takes a `dic` not a string, nor a json object.

Here was my solution:

```
schema = {}
with open(jsonSchemaFilePath, 'r') as schema_file:
    schema = json.loads(schema_file.read())

try:
    Draft4Validator.check_schema(schema)
except SchemaError as schemaError:
    print schemaError
```